# Swift segue to another View Controller in function

Tags: ios, swift, function, segue, xcode-storyboard

Hi I have tried numerous times to segue to another view controller via the use of tutorials but they don't work. Please can someone give me clear instructions on how to setup and call a segue to my next view controller. bear in mind the code for this will not be in the current view controller class.

the function runs when my player dies and so i want another view controller to appear. The function is:

```
 func playerHitSquare(player:SKSpriteNode, level1: Enemy){

    timer.invalidate()
    removeAllChildren()
}
```

The View controller i want to go to is called FinishViewController with the identifier Finish and the current view is GameViewController.

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder?  If so just use performSegue(identifier:)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add the code that is not working along with a description of the problem and answers will be more specific.

Comment: perform segue doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a nav controller, you can invoke

```
func popViewControllerAnimated(_ animated: Bool) -> UIViewController?
```

to remove the current VC and then

```
func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated animated: Bool)
```

to add the desired view controller to the nav stack and make it active. Remember, you may need to add code to your view controller classes' viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear depending

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a storyboard, you can call

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueIdentifier", sender: self)
```

In the storyboard, you have to connect the view controllers by control - dragging from the top of one VC into the the next VC and giving it an identifier name (`yourSegueIdentifier`).